# Deducing the equation using the trigonometric addition theorem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I've been in the trouble to deduce the right term from the left term.

$a\cos(\theta)+b\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}*\sin(\theta+\phi)$

$\tan(\phi)=\frac{a}{b}$

The textbook says that the right term can be gained using the trigonometric addition theorem.However I have no idea what should I do for next.

Can anyone tell me some hint(s)? so that I can deduce it on my own.

Comment: Multiply and divide the LHS by $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$\tan\phi=\dfrac ab$

$$\dfrac{\sin\phi}a=\dfrac{\cos\phi}b=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac?{a^2+b^2}}$$

Now replace the values of $a,b$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Begin by assuming that
$$a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta$$ can be written in the form
$$R\sin(x+\phi)$$
for some constants $R$ and $\phi$. Expand the second expression using the angle addition formula, form some equations, and you should have it.

---

I realize this is a bit vague, but you have asked for a hint. If you need any more help I will be happy to elaborate :)

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan \phi=\frac{a}{b}$$
Thus,
$$\cos \phi=\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
$$\sin \phi=\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
L.H.S
$$a\cos \theta +b\sin \theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\frac{\Bigl(a\cos \theta +b \sin \theta\Bigr)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\Bigl(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\cos \theta +\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} \sin \theta\Bigr)$$

I've solved most of it, you just have to apply the identity now. Hope you've got it.